# Why moment.js adds 3 minutes to a date-time when its formatted?

Tags: momentjs

When I'm formatting the date-time with moment.js, I got a strange behavior. It adds 3 minutes to the date-time.

Without specific formatting there is `08:00`

```
moment("2018-03-25T06:00:00Z").format()
"2018-03-25T08:00:00+02:00"
```

But if I format the date-time, I got `08:03`

```
moment("2018-03-25T06:00:00Z").format("YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM")
"2018/03/25 08:03"
```

Why is that?

```js
const withoutFormat = moment("2018-03-25T06:00:00Z").format();
const withFormat = moment("2018-03-25T06:00:00Z").format("YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM");

console.log(withoutFormat);
console.log(withFormat);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just because `MM` gives month number. if you want 12 hour use `h/hh` , for 24 hour `H/HH` and minute `m/mm`. Here is [doc](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

```js
const withoutFormat = moment("2018-03-25T06:00:00Z").format();
const withFormat = moment("2018-03-25T06:00:00Z").format("YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm");

console.log(withoutFormat);
console.log(withFormat);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `HH:MM` to `HH:mm` because `MM` is used for `months` in momentjs

```js
const withoutFormat = moment("2018-03-25T06:00:00Z").format();
const withFormat = moment("2018-03-25T06:00:00Z").format("YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm");

console.log(withoutFormat);
console.log(withFormat);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.js"></script>
```